# Problems setting up Roboguice 2.0 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, roboguice

OK so i've looked into this a couple of times, and I simply cannot get my project up and running with RoboGuice 2.0

Eclipse just simply doesn't recognize the annotations, eg.

```
@InjectView(R.id.link_email) TextView linkEmail;
```

I get ( in 'Problems' pane) :

'InjectView cannot be resolved to a type MyActivity.java'

'The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type InjectView'

I've followed the instructions at :

http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/InstallationNonMaven

I've got these jars in my libs folder and added to the build path :

RoboGuice 2.0,
Guice 3.0-no_aop,
jsr305

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the jar files to your eclipse project?  The step that says "Configure your IDE to add these libraries to your project"

Comment: Well I've added them to the build path - and I have access in my project to the packages within ie. RoboActivity etc., but Eclipse just doesn't like the annotations.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I was being extremely daft and the answer was pretty obvious.

I've not used the custom annotations before but unlike standard ones like '@Override' you have to import the class for Eclipse to recognise the code eg.

```
import roboguice.inject.InjectView;
```

Eclipse will autocomplete this for you in the normal manner when writing the code if you hit control and space.

Hope this helps someone else too!